# XCode 6.4 breaks Project with zipzap dependency

Tags: ios7, xcode6, cocoapods, zipzap

Up until I upgraded to XCode 6.4 the project was working fine but after the upgrade I have boiled down the build failure to zipzap.

> Using CocoaPod 0.37.2
>
> pod 'zipzap', '~> 8.0'
>
> Linked Frameworks and Libraries = libz.1.2.5.dylib
>
> Targeting iOS 7.0 +

**Build Failure**

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "___cxa_begin_catch", referenced from:
      ___clang_call_terminate in libPods-Ally-zipzap.a(ZZArchive.o)
  "std::terminate()", referenced from:
      ___clang_call_terminate in libPods-Ally-zipzap.a(ZZArchive.o)
  "___gxx_personality_v0", referenced from:
      +[ZZArchive archiveWithURL:error:] in libPods-Ally-zipzap.a(ZZArchive.o)
      +[ZZArchive archiveWithData:error:] in libPods-Ally-zipzap.a(ZZArchive.o)
      -[ZZArchive initWithURL:options:error:] in libPods-Ally-zipzap.a(ZZArchive.o)
      -[ZZArchive initWithData:options:error:] in libPods-Ally-zipzap.a(ZZArchive.o)
      -[ZZArchive initWithChannel:options:error:] in libPods-Ally-zipzap.a(ZZArchive.o)
      -[ZZArchive loadCanMiss:error:] in libPods-Ally-zipzap.a(ZZArchive.o)
      -[ZZArchive updateEntries:error:] in libPods-Ally-zipzap.a(ZZArchive.o)
      ...
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
```

**Things I have done so far**

1. For both the Project and the Pods project: Build Settings > C++ Standard Library = libstdc++ (originally was libc++)
2. couple of times pod deintegrate && rm *.lock && pod install

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've experienced this issue as well - the ZipZap podspec has been updated losing a number of compiler flags in the process:

https://github.com/pixelglow/ZipZap/commit/0e4e6aa885196640ca86462c6748e68a50c66ee9

The way I resolved this in my project was to restore the compiler flags (that were present before the update) as follows:

- Navigate to the Pods project in your workspace
- Select the Pods-zipzap target
- Select the Build Phases tab
- Expand the Compile Sources section
- Select all the Objective-C++ files (with the extension .mm) - hold the CMD key to select multiple files
- Add the compiler flags: -fno-objc-exceptions -fno-exceptions -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -DOS_OBJECT_USE_OBJC=0
- Select all Objective-C files (.m) except Pods-zipzap-dummy.m
- Add the compiler flags: -fno-objc-exceptions -std=c99 -DOS_OBJECT_USE_OBJC=0
- Select the one C++ file (.cpp)
- Add the compiler flags: -fno-exceptions -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -DOS_OBJECT_USE_OBJC=0

If you have a test target you will likely need to add the same flags there as well. All being well you should now be able to build again.

[Update]: Upgrading Cocoapods to version 0.38.0 will also resolve the errors but may result in compile errors currently with ZipZap 8.0.4 - see https://github.com/pixelglow/ZipZap/issues/105.

Alternatively, you could rollback to ZipZap 8.0.3 in your Podfile.